# capturing data from current date to a specific date

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm a fairly new to sql, and I'm using birt report designer, in which I think it is using oracle sql.
Okay I know my question will be easy, please spare me, I have done some searching and couldn't find an answer and this would be my last resort (to post here).

So this is my question,
I have a table that contains a date, example table below,

```
Student ID    Nationality    Enrollment date    
1               american            4-15-2015
2               american            1-23-2016
3               Indian              8-19-2016
4               Iranian             7-3-2015
5               Chinese             11-11-2014
6               Australian          12-1-2014
```

Since I have set this table up with the query below:

```
Select 
        a.student_ID
        a.nationality
        b.enrollment_date

    from    Infotable a
    Inner join datetable b
            On a.student_ID = b.student_ID
```

Since this sql is tied to a report I want to know what query can I use in [where] clause to show me 
the data coming from a specific date (11-11-2014) to the current date.

**To summarize it up, I want to get all the dates from a specific date to the date today.**

> or to make it a bit harder
>
> if I scheduled the report to run every Monday, next Mondays report
>   (June 6th) would have all enrollment date from
>   11/11/2014-6/6/2016.  The Monday after that would have all the enrollment date from 11/11/2014-6/13…so on and so forth.

I can do the [between] clause of to_date but I dont know what to put on the current date query.

```
b.enrollment_date BETWEEN
  TO_DATE('11-11-2014','MM-dd-yyyy') AND
  TO_DATE('7-23-2015','MM-dd-yyyy') << how can this be changed to current date?
```

I tried using sysdate but didnt work

```
b.enrollment_date BETWEEN
      TO_DATE('11-11-2014','MM-dd-yyyy') AND
      sysdate()
```

also current date didnt work too :(

```
b.enrollment_date BETWEEN
      TO_DATE('11-11-2014','MM-dd-yyyy') AND
      current_date
```

Btw, I'm using oracle so i think getdate()) might not work?

Thank you for understanding my silly question

Comment: In Oracle you'd use `sysdate`. What does "But that didnt work" mean? Did you get an error? Too many records? Too few? Something else?

Comment: And can there even be future records in the table? If not, then you don't have to specify an upper limit at all: `where b.enrollment_date >= date'2014-11-11'`.

Comment: Im getting an error when I'm using b.enrollment_date >= date'2014-11-11'

OdaDataException: Cannot get the result set metadata

Maybe I have to set the date format?

Comment: @MT0: No, it doesn't.

Comment: @user6221610: `date'2014-11-11'` is an ANSI date literal and is understood by Oracle without any setting needed.

Comment: And again: What did you mean with "But that didnt work"?

Answer (score 0):

`SYSDATE` does not need trailing brackets:

```
SELECT  a.student_ID
        a.nationality
        b.enrollment_date
FROM    Infotable a
        INNER JOIN datetable b
        ON ( a.student_ID = b.student_ID )
WHERE   b.enrollment_date BETWEEN DATE '2014-11-11' AND SYSDATE;
```

Comment: As far as I know, `SYSDATE` *is* a function. The parentheses are optional, because `SYSDATE` takes no parameter. The docs also say " this *function* returns the date and time ", so I am probably right. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm

Comment: @ThorstenKettner `SELECT SYSDATE() FROM DUAL` throws `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`.

Comment: You are right. I am sorry. I confused this. When calling a function without parameters like SYSDATE (yes it *is* a function :-) the parentheses are optional in PL/SQL and must not be used in SQL.